# Laravel Mailables - несколько значений в конструктор

Tags: php, laravel

Хочу реализовать работу с почтой на основе очередей в ларавел. Пытаюсь это сделать на основе подхода с Mailables - https://laravel.ru/posts/686.
Пишу в контроллере:

```
Mail::to(env('MAIL_ADMIN'))->send(new sendMailAdmin($user, $request));
```

Пишу в классе Mailables

```
namespace App\Mail;

use Illuminate\Bus\Queueable;
use Illuminate\Mail\Mailable;
use Illuminate\Queue\SerializesModels;
use Illuminate\Contracts\Queue\ShouldQueue;

class sendMailAdmin extends Mailable
{
    use Queueable, SerializesModels;

   public $user;
   public $request;

    /**
     * Create a new message instance.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function __construct($user, $request)
    {
        $this->user = $user;
        $this->request = $request;
    }

    /**
     * Build the message.
     *
     * @return $this
     */



    public function build()
    {

        return $this->from($this->user->email)
        ->subject($this->request->subject)->view('emails.sendAdmin');


    }
}
```

Проблема в передаче нескольких переменных-массивов в этот класс. При подходе выше получаю ошибку что Trying to get property 'subject' of non-object, но если я данном классе я просто меняю местами все объявления переменных $request и $user - получаю ошибку Trying to get property 'email' of non-object. Как мне корректно передать оба значения в этот класс, и почему так происходит?

P.s Я понял что $user это объект, а $request это массив. Вопрос изменяется на "как пробросить массив в конструктор" ?

Comment: а если попробовать `__construct(User $user, Request $request)`?

Comment: и попробуйте свериться с обновлённой документацией - https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/mail#writing-mailables